# How can I convert geotagged location to a collection of descriptive tags?

Tags: metadata, geotagging, reverse-geocoding

If I have a photo which has a geotagged location, is there a way of automatically converting this location to a collection or hierarchy of descriptive tags?

For example, a GPS location near the Olympic Park in London could be represented by the tags, "Stratford","London","England","UK","Great Britain" and "Western Europe".

This could be useful when creating tags for stock photography, or for systems which can't interpret the GPS data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is software that does [reverse geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding). Googling around shows several packages that do it. [Skyjuice](http://www.skyjuicesoftware.com/software/QuickFileRename/reverse-geocode-rename-quick-file-rename.html) is a package that claims to do it.

But [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21213/is-there-software-that-will-do-reverse-geocoding-to-convert-photographs-gps-loc) has lots more answers including the claim, unverified by me but verified in the comments below, that Lightroom 4 does it! That would be cool.

Comment: Lightroom 4 does reverse geocoding, yes; it updates the Location fields.